How to do different cases of Union Find?
Here is the question:

I understand that the absolute parents are 1, 3, 0, and 8, respectively, but I'm not sure how to do union here. Could someone help me understand how to do this?

Just blindly follow the procedures given for the $Union$ and $Find$ operations.

Please don't use images of text or mathematics.  This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; we don't like that. Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can use LaTeX.  Also, we require you to provide attribution for the source where you are obtaining this problem/material from.

To take the first question, (i).
When you want to perform union(8, 9) you do r1 = find(8) and r2 = find(9), and then you let either r1 point to r2 or vice versa.
In this case, they have the same rank, and as it says, you should break even by spring by index, hence 8 should point to 0.
